# Classic ASP Response.Status 500

Tags: asp-classic, error-handling

How do you throw a correctly formatted Status 500 error in classic asp.

I understand that Response.status = "404 File Not Found" is the correct way of handling a file not found exception but, "500 Internal Server Error" is not working when i thought it should.

Comment: If using IE, go to settings > advanced and turn off "show friendly http error messages".

Comment: IE does not seem to be giving me a nice error message even with this setting turned on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IIS you can set up a custom error pages. People do this all the time for 404 errors. You can set this for a 500 error as well.